# Find the constants for polynomial

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $f(x)=3x^4 - 2x^3+x^2+Ax +B$, where $A$ and $B$ are constants.  Find the value of $A$ and $B$ such that $x^2+4$ is a factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\pm 2i$ are roots of the dividend, hence we must have

$$3(\pm2i)^4-2(\pm2i)^3+(\pm2i)^2+A(\pm2i)+B=0$$

or

$$48\pm16i-4+A(\pm2i)+B=0$$
or
$$\begin{cases}44+B=0,\\16+2A=0.\end{cases}$$

---

Alternatively, by long division the remainder is

$$(A+8)x+(B+44).$$

Comment: I'm not sure about the $2i$ approach.  I follow your guide on using the long division method and is able to obtain the constant $A$ and $B$.  Thanks.